# How to switch CMD windows and execute a DOS command using vb script

Tags: excel, vbscript, cmd, vba

I want to open a cmd utility placed at C:\Users\123456\Desktop\Automation\Cucumber\ansi160\x64\ansicon.exe and execute below two DOS commands using VB script.

Commands,

```
1.CD C:\Users\123456\Desktop\Automation\Cucumber\ruby-1.9.3-p551-i386-mingw32\ruby-1.9.3-p551-i386-mingw32\bin 'change the directory

2.cucumber C:\Users\123456\Desktop\Automation\Cucumber\FeatureFiles\Lib_Max_Create_Lead.feature 'execute a script
```

Code i am using is -

```
Set owshell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

cmd0 = "C:\Users\123456\Desktop\Automation\Cucumber\ansi160\x64\ansicon.exe" 'for switching the cmd window

cmd1 = "cd C:\Users\123456\Desktop\Automation\Cucumber\ruby-1.9.3-p551-i386-mingw32\ruby-1.9.3-p551-i386-mingw32\bin" 'for changing the directory to ruby set up

cmd2 = "cucumber C:\Users\123456\Desktop\Automation\Cucumber\FeatureFiles\Lib_Max_Create_Lead.feature" 'for executing a script

'Execute the command

owshell.Run "%comspec% /K pushd " & "&" & cmd0 & "&" & cmd1 & "&" & cmd2
```

When i execute the above statement from a VBS file,its swtiching the window using cmd0,but the second(cmd2) & third(cmd3) commands are not getting executed.Can some one help me to correct the mistake?

Thanks in Advance

Sona Shetty

Comment: My first guess would be that the batch is waiting for ansicon.exe to complete and does not continue unless it does so. Can you verify if ansicon.exe is running when the cmd blocks and what happens if you close it?
As a side question: is there a special reason why you use a vb script to execute stuff in a batch?
Wouldn't it be easier to either use a .bat file or just run the stuff directly in vbs?